# List of all combinations of a minimum value using combn

Tags: r, combn

Here is my data:

```
      [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    2    3    4
[2,]    2    3    5
[3,]    2    3    6
[4,]    2    4    5
[5,]    2    4    6
[6,]    2    4    2
[7,]    2    4    4
[8,]    2    4    9
[9,]    2    4    10
[10,]   2    4    3
```

How would I find all combinations of column 3 that are greater than 25?  I am struggling how to use the combn function as the help function doesn't seem too intuitive.

Comment: Do the first two columns have any meaning i.e. should they somehow be considered as well?

Comment: Also, what is the operation? Summation? multiplication? Exponentiation? Please expand your question to include more details as well as your expected output.

Comment: They don't need to be considered, although I left them there since later on I will want to assign row names and reference them with the resulting vectors.

Comment: I want to return a list of vectors of the possible combinations of column 3 that are greater than (or equal*) to 25.  For instance one combination is [8,] [9,] and [3,].   The output needs to be a list of vectors with all the possible combinations that exceed 25.  I will rename each row name1,....,name10 and the list should be like [[name1]] with the combinations below. So all entries of column 3 could also be a comination.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want a non-loop version:

```
x <- read.table(text="2    3    4
2    3    5
2    3    6
2    4    5
2    4    6
2    4    2
2    4    4
2    4    9
2    4    10
2    4    3",stringsAsFactors=FALSE, header=FALSE)

res <- Map(combn, list(x[,3]), seq_along(x[,3]), simplify = FALSE)
unlist(res, recursive = FALSE)[lapply(unlist(res, recursive = FALSE),sum)>=25]

[[1]]
[1]  6  9 10

[[2]]
[1]  6  9 10

[[3]]
[1]  4  5  6 10
...
[[613]]
[1]  4  6  5  6  2  4  9 10  3

[[614]]
[1]  5  6  5  6  2  4  9 10  3

[[615]]
 [1]  4  5  6  5  6  2  4  9 10  3
```

**EDIT**
To return rownames instead of the number vector:

```
rownames(x) <- paste0("row",1:10)
res <- list(Map(combn, list(x[,3]), seq_along(x[,3]), simplify = FALSE),
 Map(combn, list(rownames(x)), seq_along(rownames(x)), simplify = FALSE))
unlist(res[[2]], recursive = FALSE)[lapply(unlist(res[[1]], recursive = FALSE),sum)>=25]

[[1]]
[1] "row3" "row8" "row9"

[[2]]
[1] "row5" "row8" "row9"

[[3]]
[1] "row1" "row2" "row3" "row9"
...
[[613]]
[1] "row1"  "row3"  "row4"  "row5"  "row6"  "row7"  "row8"  "row9"  "row10"

[[614]]
[1] "row2"  "row3"  "row4"  "row5"  "row6"  "row7"  "row8"  "row9"  "row10"

[[615]]
 [1] "row1"  "row2"  "row3"  "row4"  "row5"  "row6"  "row7"  "row8"  "row9"  "row10"
```

**EDIT2** To get the elements of the list that match the minimum sum, in this case 25. This gives you the 42 combinations that sum to 25.

```
res <- Map(combn, list(x[,3]), seq_along(x[,3]), simplify = FALSE)
res3 <- unlist(res, recursive = FALSE)[lapply(unlist(res, recursive = FALSE),sum)>=25]
res3[which(rapply(res3,sum)==min(rapply(res3,sum)))]
```

To get the corresponding rownames as asked before:

```
rownames(x) <- paste0("row",1:10)
res4 <- list(Map(combn, list(x[,3]), seq_along(x[,3]), simplify = FALSE),
            Map(combn, list(rownames(x)), seq_along(rownames(x)), simplify = FALSE))
unlist(res4[[2]], recursive = FALSE)[lapply(unlist(res4[[1]], recursive = FALSE),sum)>=25][which(rapply(res3,sum)==min(rapply(res3,sum)))]
```

Comment: That is better than mine and should be the accepted answer (upvoted). I edited my answer accordingly; I think he will soon use yours as the accepted answer...

Comment: Thanks both for the help.  Another quick question since you have been so helpful, with the resultant vectors how would I return the rownames rather than the vector values?  I didn't add the names yet but I am just about to.

Comment: I have one last question (I promise!),  at the moment I have lots of combinations that aren't too useful since I am interest in the combinations that meet the minimum criteria of >25, so once the sum of the vector values reaches 25 then I want the vector to "break" to remove the unneccesary ones.  For instance if 4 values from column 3 equal 26, then there is no need to continue adding vector values.  I still want all the possible combinations in a list with rownames that fit this criteria.

Comment: Brilliant - thanks so much.  I tried with a for loop within a for loop and things got messing trying to remove elements of each individual list.

Answer (score 1):

The following should work for a fixed length; for all combinations with variable length one would need something more advanced (EDIT: see @PLapointe's post (which should be the accepted answer) or just a simple loop):

```
x <- c(4, 5, 6, 5, 6, 2, 4, 9, 10, 3)

res <- combn(x, 3)
```

This will return a matrix that looks like this (I only show the first entries):

```
    [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10] [,11] [,12] [,13] [,14] [,15] [,16] [,17] [,18] [,19] [,20] [,21] [,22] [,23]
[1,]    4    4    4    4    4    4    4    4    4     4     4     4     4     4     4     4     4     4     4     4     4     4     4
[2,]    5    5    5    5    5    5    5    5    6     6     6     6     6     6     6     5     5     5     5     5     5     6     6
[3,]    6    5    6    2    4    9   10    3    5     6     2     4     9    10     3     6     2     4     9    10     3     2     4
```

From there, you can then just select the combinations where the column sum is larger than your threshold:

```
res[, colSums(res) >= 25]
```

This will then give

```
    [,1] [,2]
[1,]    6    6
[2,]    9    9
[3,]   10   10
```

As you now have duplicate entries (not sure if they are desired or not), you can simply do the following (or a simple loop):

```
res2 <- combn(unique(x), 3)

res2[, colSums(res2) >= 25]
```

which would then return

```
[1]  6  9 10
```

Comment: I could repeat other combinations with a for loop or just do them separately?

Comment: @Aesler: A loop would probably work which can run between 1 and length(x). But I guess there is also a smarter solution than this. Will investigate...